# How do I subtract numbers from two different list and save the results in another list c#?

Tags: c#, list

I'm wanting to subtract the difference between BillCost2016 and BillCost2015 in order and save the results in a third list. Also, is there any way to align my code to where the month and cost are aligned. I'm new to coding and any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
        List<int> BillCost2016 = new List<int>();
        BillCost2016.Add(120);
        BillCost2016.Add(220);
        BillCost2016.Add(250);
        BillCost2016.Add(180);
        BillCost2016.Add(150);
        BillCost2016.Add(260);

        List<int> BillCost2015 = new List<int>();
        BillCost2015.Add(150);
        BillCost2015.Add(210);
        BillCost2015.Add(230);
        BillCost2015.Add(180);
        BillCost2015.Add(160);
        BillCost2015.Add(280);


        List<string> BillMonth2016 = new List<string>();
        BillMonth2016.Add("Jan");
        BillMonth2016.Add("Feb");
        BillMonth2016.Add("Mar");
        BillMonth2016.Add("Apr");
        BillMonth2016.Add("May");
        BillMonth2016.Add("June");




        CombinedList(BillMonth2016, BillCost2016);

        CombinedList(BillMonth2016, BillCost2015);

        DisplayAverage2016(BillCost2016); 
        DisplayAverage2015(BillCost2015);
        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }//end main


    public static void CombinedList (List<string>Howdy, List<int>Cookie)
    {
        foreach (var cookie in Howdy)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cookie);
        }
        foreach (var candy in Cookie)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(candy);
        }

    }

    public static void DisplayAverage2016 (List<int> Howdy)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Average for 2016 is: " + Howdy.Average());


    }

    public static void DisplayAverage2015 (List<int>Howdy)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("The average for 2015 is: " + Howdy.Average());
    }




}




}
```

Comment: and to be more specific I meant subtract the difference from each item in order as they represent a particular Month's bill. So I'd need to find the difference between January 2016 cost and January 2015 cost.

Comment: How about using more modern  techniques like `public class Bill { public int year; public int month; public int value; };`

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular for cycle. Some sample code assuming both lists have the same number of elements:

```
public static List<int> differences(List<int> a, List<int> b){
    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    for(int i=0;i<a.Count;i++){
        result.Add(a[i]-b[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that both lists are correctly ordered by month, you could do the following:

```
var billDifference = BillCost2015.Zip(BillCost2016, (f, s) => f - s);
```

That said, you should probably think in a better way to store your bill information. Create a class that represents all signifcant data of a bill; year, month, day, value, etc. and work with `List<Bill>`.